# How to perform exception handling in a loop in Google Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to take monthly backup of multiple tables present in various datasets by exporting the data to GCS using **EXPORT DATA OPTIONS** command. These table names are present in another table in the following schema which would be maintained by someone

```
| Sr.No | Table_Name                            | Date_filter   | Timeline |
|-------|---------------------------------------|---------------|----------|
| 1     | gcs_project_name.dataset_name.table1  | inserted_date | Monthly  |
| 2     | gcs_project_name.dataset_name2.table2 | inserted_date | Monthly  |
```

I wrote a script in procedural language to make an array of such query strings which would perform the export one table at a time on the bases of the Date_filter. The script doing so is mentioned below

```
DECLARE folder_name DEFAULT CAST(DATE(CURRENT_DATE()) AS STRING);

DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE dynamic_query ARRAY <STRING>;

SET dynamic_query = ([![SELECT ARRAY_AGG(CONCAT("EXPORT DATA OPTIONS (uri = 'gs://data_backup/",folder_name,'/',Table_Name,"_*',\n format = 'CSV',","\n overwrite = TRUE,","\n header = TRUE,","\n field_delimiter = ',') AS","\n\n SELECT * FROM \n","   `",Table_Name,"`\n","WHERE \n DATE(",Date_filter,") BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 month), month) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 month), month)","\n LIMIT \n 1000000",";","\n")) FROM `google_sheets.backup_tables`][1]][1] );

LOOP
  SET i = i + 1;
  IF i > ARRAY_LENGTH(dynamic_query) THEN 
    SET boolean = FALSE;
    LEAVE; 
  END IF;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamic_query[ORDINAL(i)];
END LOOP; 

SELECT dynamic_query;
```

The output of the dynamic_query is mentioned below

[image]

Now I'm iterating over this array and executing the queries one-by-one using **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE**

The issue I'm facing is that the field mentioned in Date_filter is sometime in STRING datatype. Due to this the script fails and doesn't continue the execution for remaining tables. To tackle this I want to perform exception handling where the execution doesn't stop and I'm able to see the list of tables which have been exported and failed, just like python's try-catch block.

Comment: It should solve your issue: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#beginexceptionend

Comment: See also https://medium.com/google-cloud/hidden-gems-of-bigquery-p7-safety-first-e4668fa4f248

Comment: The idea is to use these statements in the following manner ```for item in array: try: some_operations(item) except Exception as e: print(e)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to perform exception handling in Loop command. Here's the code for reference

```
DECLARE folder_name DEFAULT CAST(DATE(CURRENT_DATE()) AS STRING);

DECLARE i INT64 DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE dynamic_query ARRAY <STRING>;

SET dynamic_query = (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(CONCAT("EXPORT DATA OPTIONS (uri = 'gs://data_backup/",folder_name,'/',Table_Name,"_*',\n format = 'CSV',","\n overwrite = TRUE,","\n header = TRUE,","\n field_delimiter = ',') AS","\n\n SELECT * FROM \n","   `",Table_Name,"`\n","WHERE \n DATE(",Date_filter,") BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 month), month) AND LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 month), month)","\n LIMIT \n 1000000",";","\n")) FROM `google_sheets.backup_tables` );

  LOOP
    BEGIN
    SET i = i + 1;
    IF i > ARRAY_LENGTH(dynamic_query) THEN 
      SET boolean = FALSE;
      LEAVE; 
    END IF;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamic_query[ORDINAL(i)];
    
    EXCEPTION WHEN ERROR THEN
    
    SELECT @@error.message;
    
    END;
    
    CONTINUE;
  
  END LOOP;
```